# Changing a component to a container seems to break Routes in that component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm running in to a problem where making a component that houses Routes in to a container seems to break react router. If the component that houses my routes is a container then clicking a Link updates the URL but doesn't change the screen rendered. If I refresh the page once the URL has changed or go directly to the url it renders the expected view. Changing the container back to regular component seems to fix this issue but I'd like to keep it as a container so I can use the necessary actions.

Routes broken:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import '../styles/App.css';
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Home from './Home'
import NewPost from './NewPost'
import { getAllPosts, getAllCategories } from '../actions'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllPosts()
    this.props.getAllCategories()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
          <Home />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/post" render={() => (
          <NewPost />
        )} />
        
        <Route path="/article" render={() => (
          <div>article page</div>
        )} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    getAllPosts, 
    getAllCategories
  }, dispatch)
)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Routes working:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import '../styles/App.css';
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Home from './Home'
import NewPost from './NewPost'
import { getAllPosts, getAllCategories } from '../actions'

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //this.props.getAllPosts()
    //this.props.getAllCategories()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
          <Home />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/post" render={() => (
          <NewPost />
        )} />
        
        <Route path="/article" render={() => (
          <div>article page</div>
        )} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    getAllPosts, 
    getAllCategories
  }, dispatch)
)

// export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Any help with this would be massively appreciated, it's been driving me crazy!

Edit: For clarity here's my index.js which has the wrapping BrowserRouter:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

// Middleware
import logger from 'redux-logger'

// Martyware
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import App from './containers/App';

import './styles/index.css';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    applyMiddleware(logger)
  )
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: So what's the main different between broken and working example? Is it the working example doesn't do get method at componentDidMount?

Comment: The main difference is that in the working example I'm not using connect() from react-redux that's the part at which it seems to break. In the working example I'm just exporting the class directly. 

I've tested this component without calling the methods in componentDidMount whilst continuing to use connect and the resulting behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to consider, but in short, I think that your issue is happening because your component does not re-render as it's unaware that the location has changed. The quick solution to this is to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
...
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

Now, there are other aspects of your code that indicate potential issues. The `<Router />` is not visible so we can only assume that it wraps your component at a higher level. You did not map any Redux state to props, so that will not be causing a re-render either.

**Why do you need withRouter?**

As requested, I will try to explain what effect `withRouter` has, but for this I need to get into how React components re-render. In order to prevent constant re-render, React looks at the result of the method `componentShouldUpdate`, which by default compares the props (and state) of such component, and if they changed it calls the `render` function. If they have not changed it does not.

So, when you have a component which contains `<Route />` (`<App />` in your example), whether or not the location changes, the `<App />` props and state do not change, and as such, the `render` function is not called again. If it is not called again, the `<Route />` that matches your path will not asked to re-render. In short, if your parent component did not re-render, its children will not either. That is typically why tools like Redux exist, to be able to update a component deep in the tree without having to pass all properties down from the parents.

What `withRouter` does is that it adds the properties `location` (and others) to your `<App />` component, in such that whenever the location changes, the props effectively changed, and as such a re-render is forced. Whether or not your component is wrapped in Redux's `connect()` does not affect this.

So, why did it work when you did not have `<App />` but everything in the same component? Well, that is because your main component re-rendered, and so each of the components present in `render` were asked whether they wanted to re-render too.

Obviously the performance of using `withRouter` are not great because you may cause re-render way more often than you'd like. But that is your job to organise such component in a way that the least amount of work is done upon re-render. You will likely use sub-components which rely on their own props to be looked at, and not the `location` itself.

There are also ways to put use React Router with Redux, where I assume you do not need `withRouter`, but would effectively be the same where Redux will cause a change in your props which will trigger a re-render. I have not looked into this, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the help. Adding withRouter fixed it right away! I've added the index.js with the wrapping browserrouter to my question for clarity. 

I'm not mapping redux state to props here since this particular component isn't making use of it yet. 

I'd love to understand why withRouter solves the problem and why the render isn't being triggered when I use connect. Do you have any suggestions on what I can read up on to better understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've since found this article that explains the issue in detail https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

From what I understand connect is blocking the re rendering of the component because it calls shouldComponentUpdate in a way that blocks re rendering. Using withRouter works but is not the most efficient solution (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5552#issuecomment-331502281)

The solution I've ended up using is rendering App through a pathless route (which will always match and therefore render App) in index.js here's the updated render method from index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I hope that can be useful for someone. Many, many thanks to FMCorz for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I've added more explanation to my answer.